# Processing MultiDimensional Array of Variable Length

Tags: ruby, groovy, logic

I want to create data sets from variable length multidimensional arrays, but I'm not sure how best to go about it.

I've thought of calculating the permutation of the array and then looping through the values to create the new data set, but that approach seems fragile.

Below are example inputs and outputs.

**Input**

```
[ [id: "Denver", value: ['$', '%']], [id: "datestamp", value: [201106]], [id: "price", value: [1, 2]] ]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[ ["Denver$2011061"], ["Denver%2011061"], ["Denver$2011062"], ["Denver%2011062"] ]
```

Comment: And what code have you written?

Comment: @the Tin Man: Up to this point I wrote (Groovy) code that calculates the permutation of 'n' data sets. I was in the process of writing a method that would iterate over the data sets as per the resultant permutation. However, at this point there is no point continuing with that approach, because the 'combinations' method, which was previously unknown to me, does exactly what I was trying to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming in Groovy, you have:

```
def data = [ [id: "Denver", value: ['$', '%']], [id: "datestamp", value: [201106]], [id: "price", value: [1, 2]] ]
```

Then you can do:

```
def output = data*.value.combinations()*.join('').collect { [ "${data[0].id}$it" ] }
```

And output will have the value:

```
[[Denver$2011061], [Denver%2011061], [Denver$2011062], [Denver%2011062]]
```

Comment: +1 @tim, that is nicely done ;--) Curious to see the Ruby equivalent

Comment: @virtual Me too!  Or indeed a better Groovy version (there probably is one) :)

Comment: Thanks for the clean and simple example; I was unaware that Groovy collections had the static method 'combinations.' I was unnecessarily trying to (re)implement that very functionality and so far the code for it is rather ugly...